# How to validate tab in jText Area?

Tags: java

I would like to validate tab in the java text area because input is saved in text file split by tab. If I type tab, it will not read the next input. I have tried,for example: String.matches("\t"), but it is not working.
Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
String Title = textfield.getText();
String Description = textarea.getText();

if (Description.matches("\t"))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Tab is not allowed");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File("Data.txt");

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(f,true)))
        {           
             writer.write(Title+"\t"+Description+System.lineSeparator());         
        }
     }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching for a single tab character or a tab character inside a larger string? If it is the latter try:

```
Description.matches(".*\t.*")
```

Comment: It is working! Thank you so much! Can you please explain these code?

Comment: The point matches any character, the * means "previous expressión (the point) many times". So this regex means: "any number of characters (zero or more) followed by a tab character followed by any number of characters".

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you!